# Unable to save readLine(); to the string variable

Tags: java, readline

I'm trying to save readLine() output to the variable (it contains only one single line) to compare this lines in the future. But variables do not change their values:

```
try {
                        String VersName = "src/bin/version.txt";
                        BufferedReader br = null;
                        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(VersName));
                        URL url = new URL("ftp://31.130.206.175/current_versions/vers");

                        // read text returned by server
                        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
                        System.out.println(br.readLine());
                        System.out.println(in.readLine());

                        String aa = null;
                        String bb = null;
                        aa = br.readLine();
                        bb = in.readLine();
                        System.out.println("***" + aa + "***" + bb + "***");

                        in.close();
                        br.close();

                    } catch (MalformedURLException e3) {
                        System.out.println("Malformed URL");
                    } catch (IOException e4) {
                        System.out.println("I/O Error");
                    }
```

Output:

```
0.0.0
0.1.0
***null***null***
```

When I'm trying to covert them to Strings (aa = br.readLine().toString();), I have an exception:

```
0.0.0
0.1.0
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Launcher.SimpleSwingBrowser$3.actionPerformed(SimpleSwingBrowser.java:209)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6535)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6300)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4891)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Is there any way to save them to variable?

Thank you.

Comment: If the data only contains one line why are you calling `readLine()` four times? But the output you have provided shows clearly *two* lines: your explanation? And what is `in`, and what is the basis for your belief that it isn't null?

Comment: @OP Don't vandalise your own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is here

```
System.out.println(br.readLine());
System.out.println(in.readLine());
```

You read your line, so it is no longer available for your

```
aa = br.readLine();
bb = in.readLine();
```

And so you read nothing.

Try to reorder your instructionslike this (for example):

```
String aa = br.readLine();
String bb = in.readLine();

System.out.println(aa);
System.out.println(bb);
```

It should be better ;)